# How to connect to database via VPN?

Tags: mysql-workbench, dbeaver

I have installed OPENVPN client on linux mint. I am able to connect to it and access the client's jekins server, etc. via browser, however I am not able to connect to their database through dbeaver or mysqlworkbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. Seems like sql Clients are not able to resolve the hostname while in VPN. I had the provide the IP address in place of hostname.

Comment: If it is in VPN configuration, then I guess the IP is the internal one ?